# mybatis enum custom handler error

Tags: java, enums, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have a userModel which contains two enum. I write a custom enum handler for both of them. When select the userModel, the handler get the second enum type, but the first enum type column name. Therefore, there is error. Do you know how to solve this?

My handler:

```
@MappedTypes({UserType.class, AccountType.class})
public class HasValueEnumTypeHandler<E extends Enum<E> & HasValue> extends BaseTypeHandler<E> {
private Class<E> type;
private final E[] enums;
private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

public HasValueEnumTypeHandler(Class<E> type) {
    if (type == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Type argument cannot be null");
    this.type = type;
    this.enums = type.getEnumConstants();
    if (this.enums == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(type.getSimpleName() + " does not represent an enum type.");
}


@Override
public E getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
    int value = rs.getInt(columnName);
    if (rs.wasNull()) {
        return null;
    }
    for (E enm : enums) {
        if (value == enm.getValue()) {
            return enm;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot convert " + value + " to " + type.getSimpleName());
}

@Override
public E getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnName) throws SQLException {
    int value = rs.getInt(columnName);
    if (rs.wasNull()) {
        return null;
    }
    for (E enm : enums) {
        if (value == enm.getValue()) {
            return enm;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot convert " + value + " to " + type.getSimpleName());
}

@Override
public E getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnName) throws SQLException {
    int value = cs.getInt(columnName);
    if (cs.wasNull()) {
        return null;
    }
    for (E enm : enums) {
        if (value == enm.getValue()) {
            return enm;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot convert " + value + " to " + type.getSimpleName());
}

@Override
public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, E parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
    ps.setInt(i, parameter.getValue());
}
```

}

My mapper.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd" >
<mapper namespace="com.rmword.mapper.UserModelMapper">

<resultMap type="com.rmword.model.UserModel" id="usermap">
    <id column="user_id" property="userId" />
    <result column="password" property="password" />
    <result column="token" property="token" />
    <result column="register_time" property="registerTime" />
    <result column="user_type" property="userType"
        typeHandler="com.rmword.utils.HasValueEnumTypeHandler" />
    <result column="account_type" property="accountType"
        typeHandler="com.rmword.utils.HasValueEnumTypeHandler" />
</resultMap>

<insert id="insertUser">
    insert into user (user_id, password, token,
    register_time, user_type, account_type) values (
    #{userId},
    #{password}, #{token}, #{registerTime},
    #{userType, typeHandler=com.rmword.utils.HasValueEnumTypeHandler},
    #{accountType,
    typeHandler=com.rmword.utils.HasValueEnumTypeHandler}
    )
</insert>

<select id="selectUserById" parameterType="String" resultMap="usermap">
    select * from user where user_id = #{userId}
</select>
```

My two enum:

```
public enum AccountType implements HasValue {
EMAIL(1),
QQ(2),
WEIBO(3);

int value;

AccountType(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}
}

public enum UserType implements HasValue {
RMWORD(1);

int value;

UserType(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}
}
```

The error is

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Could not set property 'userType' of 'class com.rmword.model.UserModel' with value 'EMAIL' Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

It mix the two enums.